# How to add SAML2 service provider with SingleLogoutService URL to jumpcloud?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, component-space, single-logout

I am working on a Asp.Net MVC Web applications. We have requirement to implemented SSO and SLO. My applications (at least 2 applications) are acting as service provider (SP) and I am using Jumpcloud as Identity Provider (IdP). I want to add application on jumpcloud using SAML with service provider SingleLogoutService URL. But there is no option to add SingleLogoutService URL on Jumpcloud.

How do I add SingleLogoutService URL for an application on Jumpcloud?
How do I get SingleLogoutService URL of Jumpcloud (Identity Provider)? The export metadata on Jumpcloud do not have SingleLogoutService.

I am using ComponentSpace 2.6.0.2 for SSO and using low-level APIs. SSO has been already implemented and it is working fine.

Sample IdP metadata exported from Jumpcloud

Removed data for brevity
            
        
        
        urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:nameid-format:unspecified

Comment: Although [this](https://support.jumpcloud.com/customer/portal/questions/16853689-saml-logout-feature) is dated 2017 but chances are it still holds, i.e. they don't support single logouts.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The link mentioned IdP-initiated SAML Single Logout feature not supported. However I want perform SP-Initiated Single Logout.

Comment: Chances are they assume the SLO endpoint at your side should be the same endpoint SSO uses. What if you send the LogoutRequest to the SAML endpoint? Is there any response back? If not, they could be not supporting any form of SLO,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether JumpCloud supports SLO or not. I posted a request for SLO featuer and not received any reply yet.

While googling I found following URL which can be setup as SLO URL:
https://console.jumpcloud.com/userconsole

However I am not sure it will work or not.

Since I don't want to spend more time on research, so I switch to Okta, and Okta support Single Logout.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but I've had the same and JumpCloud still doesn't support SLO (as of Dec. 2023). You can use Okta instead. Setup details are here: https://help.okta.com/en-us/content/topics/apps/aiw-saml-reference.htm